# Problems migrating PHPList to new VPS server

Tags: centos, cpanel

I am trying to migrate an installation of PHPlist via the Installatron installer provided by the cPanel console on a VPS. This error occurs in red under the URL heading:

```
! This import will require 1MB of available disk space to complete. Sufficient disk space is currently not available.

For assistance or to add additional disk space, contact your web hosting administrator.

Technical Error: Unable to create directory `/public_html/phplist'.
```

I went into SSH and created the /public_html/phplist folder using mkdir and the problem still persists. It's a newly leased server with 60GB of space -- 1mb shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Read message. `Sufficient disk space is currently not available.`Check quota for user.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note for anyone facing this error which is totally non-explanatory in what the problem actually is:

In `Installatron`, when you choose the SSH option, as you should, you need to specify the full path to the files. Not just from the user directory.

So, normally it might say `public_html/blog`, and you will need to change that to say, `/home/user/public_html/blog`.

Now enter the full path and SSH will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This error only occurred when the "ssh" option was selected in the Installatron import settings. After switching to ftp the error disappeared.

Comment: SSH is generally considered preferable to FTP because FTP is insecure. If the system is supposed to support SSH, then a good solution would allow for the continued use of SSH.

Comment: @user691519 you are correct in this case, although SSH is the preferred method it also causing the same issue here